# How can I return a list of vnets with IDs while filtering out the hub vnet (hub/spoke) design in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to return the names and ID's of our spoke networks for input into an azurerm peering block.  I initially tried using an additional attribute on the vnet input to define which was a spoke and which was a hub. This failed because I couldn't figure out how to combine a list of vnet names and IDs with the vnet map(objects).  The second approach was to just pass in all vnets from azurerm_virtual_network and then filter them in the child module.  I couldn't get that to work either for the same reason.  I finally found azurerm_resources, which even has an example tailored specifically to what I'm trying to do... and it doesn't work.

This is the azurerm data source we're trying to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resources and the example.

```
# Get resources by type, create spoke vNet peerings
data "azurerm_resources" "spokes" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"

  required_tags = {
    environment = "production"
    role        = "spokeNetwork"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "spoke_peers" {
  count = length(data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources)

  name                      = "hub2${data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources[count.index].name}"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.hub.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.hub.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources[count.index].id
}
```

I briefly tried to turn that into a for_each, gave up, then modified the values to map our environment and used terraform plan.

```
data "azurerm_resources" "spokes" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"

  required_tags = {
    role        = "spokeNetwork"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peer-hub-spoke-eastus" {
  count = length(data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources)

  name                      = "peer-hub-to-${data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources[count.index].name}"
  resource_group_name       = var.rg_network_name
  virtual_network_name      = var.vnet_hub_name
  remote_virtual_network_id = data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources[count.index].id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
  allow_gateway_transit        = false
}
```

What we receive is:

```
Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on modules\networking\modules\Fortigate\Active-Active-ELB-ILB\00-main.tf line 91, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peer-hub-spoke-eastus":
│   91:   count = length(data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources)
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
╵
```

I did run an apply with -target against azurerm_resources and azurerm_virtual_network, neither of which resolved my error.  We receive something similar if we use for_each.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm completely open to approaching this a different way.

Comment: "I did run an apply with -target against azurerm_resources and azurerm_virtual_network, neither of which resolved my error." - then you did that incorrectly. Since you haven't provided any relevant information on the use of `-target` its difficult to speculate what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Apply / Target apply should work, I have tried the below code and tested it.

You need to make sure that the `azurerm_virtual_network.hub` and `azurerm_virtual_network.spoke*` resources are deployed/applied before planning for `azurerm_virtual_network_peering` resources. If you want to use a single root module then it has to be done in 2 steps, either via partial apply(comment peering config) or `-target` flag.

#### Terraform code

- Apply the below section first.

```
locals {
  spoke_tags = {
    environment = "production"
    role        = "spokeNetwork"
  }
  hub_tags = {
    environment = "production"
    role        = "hubNetwork"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "hub" {
  name     = "iamawesomerg-hub"
  location = "west europe"
  tags     = local.hub_tags
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "spokes" {
  name     = "iamawesomerg-spoke"
  location = "west europe"
  tags     = local.spoke_tags
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "hub" {
  name                = "hub"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.hub.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.hub.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  tags                = local.hub_tags
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spoke1" {
  name                = "spoke1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.hub.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.hub.name
  address_space       = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
  tags                = local.spoke_tags
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spoke2" {
  name                = "spoke2"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.hub.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.hub.name
  address_space       = ["10.3.0.0/16"]
  tags                = local.spoke_tags
}

## As the resources are deployed in the same root module, we need to wait for a few seconds to let the data source read the vnets with tags, else it **might** can skip too.

resource "null_resource" "wait_for_vnet_provisioning" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "for i in $(seq 10); do echo wait for Vnet provisioning; sleep 1; done"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.hub,
    azurerm_virtual_network.spoke1,
    azurerm_virtual_network.spoke2
  ]
}

data "azurerm_resources" "spokes" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"

  required_tags = {
    environment = "production"
    role        = "spokeNetwork"
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning]
}

locals {
  spokes = data.azurerm_resources.spokes.resources
}

/*
This code is commented as of now as the local.spokes won't be available until you apply. 
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peer-hub-spoke-eastus" {
  count = length(local.spokes)

  name                      = "peer-hub-to-${local.spokes[count.index].name}"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.hub.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.hub.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = local.spokes[count.index].id
  allow_forwarded_traffic   = true
  allow_gateway_transit     = false
}
*/
```

- Apply Status for the above section.

```bash
Plan: 6 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
azurerm_resource_group.hub: Creating...
azurerm_resource_group.spokes: Creating...
azurerm_resource_group.spokes: Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-spoke]
azurerm_resource_group.hub: Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub]
azurerm_virtual_network.hub: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network.spoke1: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network.spoke2: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network.spoke2: Creation complete after 6s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/spoke2]
azurerm_virtual_network.spoke1: Creation complete after 6s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/spoke1]
azurerm_virtual_network.hub: Creation complete after 6s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub]
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning: Creating...
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "for i in $(seq 10); do echo wait for vpc provisioning; sleep 1; done"]
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning (local-exec): wait for vpc provisioning
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
null_resource.wait_for_vnet_provisioning: Creation complete after 10s [id=7661238397153374354]
data.azurerm_resources.spokes: Reading...
data.azurerm_resources.spokes: Read complete after 1s [id=resource-cfbf9baf-beae-4e21-8e3f-b71eb55843ac]

Apply complete! Resources: 6 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

- Once the above resources are deployed/applied. (without peering resources)

Then it is safe to uncomment the `azurerm_virtual_network_peering` resource and apply the entire config.

> Apply the uncommented `azurerm_virtual_network_peering` resource.

```bash
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[1]: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[0]: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[1]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[0]: Creation complete after 11s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub/virtualNetworkPeerings/peer-hub-to-spoke1]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[1]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.peer-hub-spoke-eastus[1]: Creation complete after 22s [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iamawesomerg-hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub/virtualNetworkPeerings/peer-hub-to-spoke2]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```